# Pulling specific data from spreadsheet cell and populating corresponding cells

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goal: Pull Gmail into spreadsheet, pull specific data from cell and populate other cells

Pulling the gmail into the sheet works. Extracting the data works but it doesn't put the data in a single row it put it in several rows and each row will add a column of data. Below is a link to the google sheet so you can see exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. In row 1 I've accomplished my goal using google sheet formulas but that requires multiple hidden columns.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Gmail');
  menu.addItem('Get Gmail', 'getGmail')
  menu.addToUi();
}


function getGmail(){
 
 
 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Billing");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
 
  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
     
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}


function extractDetails(message){
 
  var emailData = {
    date: "Null",
    sender: "Null",
    subject: "Null",
    body: "Null",
    recipient: "Null",
    amount: "Null",
    fee: "Null",
    total: "Null"
  }
 
  var emailKeywords = {
    recipient: "Recipient:*",
    amount: "Amount Sent",
    fee: "Fee",
    total: "Total Amount Charged*"
  }
 
  emailData.date = message.getDate();
  emailData.sender = message.getFrom();
  emailData.subject = message.getSubject();
  emailData.body = message.getPlainBody();
 
  var regExp;
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.recipient + ").*");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
  
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.amount +").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.fee + ").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.fee = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 
  var emailDataArr = [];
 
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
 
 
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
 
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14FuuKS2ChZ_O687D2ybGvg0ZhfGvHnuzUpAx6oIulg4/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

It is difficult to provide you some help as I don't understand how *Pulling the gmail into the sheet works* if the error appears before writing to the sheet *`activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);`*.

### What I see

Looking at your code and the error you get, I think the problem is in the thread/message handling. For example, the line `threads[i].Removelabel(label);` should be outside `for (var j = 0; j < messages.Length; j++)`.

### Suggestion

I suggest you use [logs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#use_the_apps_script_execution_log) to see how the algorithm is collecting the different data. Try simply putting `console.log(variable)` in different parts of your code.

Finally, I advice that when you share a Spreadsheet document, do not disable the `export options`, because then I cannot create a copy of it to test the code. In addition, it would also be useful to have some mails to be able to reproduce all the steps. You could create a function in which these messages are sent, or at least show how they look like.

### Reference

- [Use the Apps Script execution log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#use_the_apps_script_execution_log)

Comment: That solved that problem but now running into a new problem.                    
 SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=*Recipient:*).*/: Nothing to repeat
    at extractDetails(Code:57:12)
    at getGmailEmails(Code:25:7)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with a workaround using Google formulas to parse the data instead of Google scripts. It's a little sloppy considering I had to add extra columns and hide them to accomplish my goal and if you're anything like me you hate sloppy workarounds like this but nonetheless it works. For anyone looking to see the solution I was able to create with the formulas refer to the above spreadsheet. I'm going to keep trying the Google scripts to make it cleaner

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you find my answer helpful, please accept it for documentation purposes. If you would like to receive more help, please consider editing the question with the suggestions I have given you in the answer.

Comment: I was able to get the data to extract. I edited the post. Only issue I'm having currently is the data isn't being added across the same row. I added a screenshot above. Any suggestions on how to get it to only produce one row with all the data in that row?

Comment: Hey, I still can't make a copy of the Spreadsheet. This is because you have the [export options](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?visit_id=637623070179389852-2751143223&p=disable_download&rd=1#disable&zippy=%2Cdont-let-people-download-print-or-copy-your-file) disabled. By the way, have you made any progress?

Comment: I just added the answer below. Check it out it works great now :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Gmail');
  menu.addItem('Get Gmail', 'getGmail')
  menu.addToUi();
}


function getGmail(){
 
 
 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Billing");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
 
  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
     
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}


function extractDetails(message){
 
  var emailData = {
    date: "Null",
    sender: "Null",
    subject: "Null",
    body: "Null",
    recipient: "Null",
    amount: "Null",
    fee: "Null",
    total: "Null"
  }
 
  var emailKeywords = {
    recipient: "Recipient:*",
    amount: "Amount Sent",
    fee: "Fee",
    total: "Total Amount Charged*"
  }
 
  emailData.date = message.getDate();
  emailData.sender = message.getFrom();
  emailData.subject = message.getSubject();
  emailData.body = message.getPlainBody();
 
  var regExp;
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.recipient + ").*");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
  
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.amount +").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.fee + ").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.fee = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 
  var emailDataArr = [];
 
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
 
  }
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
}
```